# Where did The Doctor put his legs in Davros' chair?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode, *The Witch's Familiar,* The Doctor sits in Davros' chair.

However, the aforementioned character has no legs. Furthermore, his lower body consists of what appear to be cables to link him to the chair. Hence, he has no need for legroom.

So where did The Doctor put his legs?

Comment: I'm guessing he simply tore out some life-support machinery in the base to make more legroom.

Comment: @ixrec: but Davros sat in it later. It wasn't a spare, there were only two chairs on Skaros.

Comment: Yay! Now ask why there were two chairs on Skaro ;)

Comment: @Wikis He probably needed Sarff's help to get back in the chair anyway (and go find the second chair, lol) so Sarff could've simply undone whatever hasty modifications the Doctor made.

Comment: Anyway, why wouldn't the chair have some legroom, even if Davros wouldn't need it.

Comment: If there were two chairs on Skaro, logic suggests that they both belonged to Davros. (Da-leks have no conception of chairs!) One was clearly a life-support device. Clearly, then, the other had some sort of sentimental value to Davros. I suspect it was the style of chair he sat in when was young, or when he was healthy. There is also the possibility he had it made beforehand for the Doctor.

Comment: _The real question, of course, is where did I get the cup of tea? Answer: I’m the Doctor – just accept it._

Comment: Having just seen an officially released Youtube video that reflects on this, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you're the god of a species that dominates the planet you live on, why scrimp on space?

- Since the Doctor could sit in the chair, there must have been legroom inside it.
- Since Davros apparently has no legs, the cables poking out of his lower body must have been attached to some contacts inside the chair.

Ergo, the inside of the chair had **more room than was necessary**. Simple explanation, and the only thing that makes sense.

---

Alternatively, how about an in-universe explanation inspired by an out-of-universe one? Perhaps there wasn't really specially designed legroom inside the chair, but the Doctor could crouch with his legs folded beneath him. Just as Peter Capaldi did in reality (image links to Youtube video):

[image: chair]

Comment: I assumed that it was because Davros had legs, was confined to a wheelchair, and after not using them for who knows how long they have withered.

Comment: Didn't Davros have visible legs in "Genesis of the Daleks"?  I'd not be surprised if he's been tinkering with the same wheelchair ever since then.

Comment: This should really be best answer.

Comment: @Hashim Well, I agree, but tell that to the OP :-)